# ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, process

I'm printing a pdf directly towards a printer, but I want to do this in the background.
At the moment everything is working, but you can see that adobe is starting up and opening a document, while I want that to stay hidden.

For this I tried to use:

```
Process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
```

But it won't work, while I do everything the same as written in:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx#Y0)

It is mentioned that you should place

```
psi.UseShellExecute = False
```

In order to let CreateNoWindow work, but when I place this in my code I get an error message: The system cannot find the file specified, while without this line, it works.

Below you can find the entire code:

```
            Dim Process1 As New System.Diagnostics.Process
            Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("AcroRd32.exe", "/t " + temppdf + " " + General.pdfprinter + "")
            'psi.UseShellExecute = False
            psi.CreateNoWindow = True
            Process1.StartInfo = psi
            Process1.Start()
            Process1.WaitForInputIdle()
            Process1.Kill()
```

Any idea?

Comment: CreateNoWindow can only have an affect on console mode programs.  Acrobat Reader is not.  Bad name, they should have picked "CreateNoConsole".  You can ask it to *minimize* its main window with WindowStyle, it might comply if it doesn't feel like spamming you.

Comment: Thanks Hans,

So it seems that there is no way to hide Acrobat during its activity?

Comment: I gave you a very specific tip, it is up to you to try it.

Comment: I tried psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized as well, but it still comes up in front of the window.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Define the function ShowWindow:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As ShowWindowCommands) As Boolean
End Function
```

And then call it:

```
Process1.Start()
ShowWindow(Process1.MainWindowHandle, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the same thing is happening.

Comment: A properly written GUI program ignores ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden.  Because that's a trap, the user could only stop the program by using Task Manager.  Also the reason this option isn't offered in the shortcut properties dialog.

Comment: I tried it, but its also not working.
The pdf is opening before it goes into the showwindow function.